# Get Settings->Developer options->Device hostname by ip

Tags: java, android, ip, hostname

How can I get Settings->Developer options->Device hostname of another device on same network?
Tried this:

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.7");
Log.i("address.getHostName", address.getHostName());
Log.i("address.getCanonicalHostName", address.getCanonicalHostName());
```

but it returns same ip address...

I saw working example only in samsungs android version in wifi ap settings, where it shows this hostname of connected device - http://goo.gl/1CoeTu

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on whether or not the other hosts on the network support some sort of zeroconf setup, and how android implements it.  I suspect you don't have a DNS server on your local network?

Comment: Well no, I'm currently impoving cyanogenmods wifi tethering stuff and I want to view hosts in list of connected devices too...any other solutions?

Comment: No solutions as such, but I would suggest looking at what the getHostName method does, and then making sure that information is in place.